# Flask sqlalchemy updating multiple fields in a row

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Recently moved to flask from expressjs.
I am creating a flask app using `flask flask-sqlalchemy flask-wtf`

It is a form heavy application. I expect to have about 30-50 forms, with each form having 20-100 fields.

Client side forms are using `flask-wtf`

I am able to create models and able to create a crud functionality. The problem is that with each form I have to manually do

IN CREATE
[...]

```
# after validation
someItem = SomeModel(someField1=form.someField1.data, ..., somefieldN = form.someFieldN.data)
db.session.add(someItem) 
db.session.commit()
```

IN UPDATE

```
[....]
queryItem = SomeModel.query.filter_by(id=item_id)
queryItem.somefield1 = form.someField1.data
[...]
queryItem.somefieldN = form.someFieldN.data

db.session.commit()
```

As apparent, with lots of forms, it gets very tedious. Is there a way to 
If you are able to suggest a library that will do this 
I have searched online for the last few hours. The closest I got to was to create a dictionary and then pass it like

```
someDict = {'someField1': form.someField1.data, ....}
SomeModel.query.filter_by(id=item.id).update(someDict)
```

As you can see it is equally tedious

I am hoping to find a way to pass the form data directly to `SomeModel` for creating as well as updating.
I previously used expressjs + knex and I was simply able to pass req.body after validation, to knex.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Use 'populate_obj' (note: model field names must match form fields)

Create record:

```
someItem = SomeModel()
form.populate_obj(someItem)
db.session.add(someItem)
db.session.commit()
```

Update record:

```
queryItem = SomeModel.query.filter_by(id=item_id)
form.populate_obj(queryItem)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and report back